# Running checksum check on an application - OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, checksum

Ive just read about the issue with Malware inside of handbrake for OSX - [link to article on hacker news.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14332741)

Ive got handbrake installed on a few computers of mine, so wanted to check wether i had an infected copy. To do this i ran the following terminal command as suggested via [handbrakes checksum page.](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/wiki/Checksums)

**COMMAND :** `cd /Applications shasum -a 1 HandBrake-* && shasum -a 256 HandBrake-`

From this i got the following response which seems to be blank.. any ideas wether this is saying that i have an infected file or if ive just run the initial terminal command wrong ?

**RESPONSE :** `shasum: HandBrake-: Sams-MacBook-Pro:Applications Sam$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the instructions on the HandBrake website are for checking the original `.dmg` file downloaded and saved in the `~/Downloads` directory:

```
~/Downloads/HandBrake-1.0.7.dmg
```

Open Terminal.app

```
cd ~/Downloads
shasum -a 1 HandBrake-* && shasum -a 256 HandBrake-*
```

**Result**:

```
6d2e5158f101dad94ede3d5cf5fda8fe9fd3c3b9  HandBrake-1.0.7.dmg
3cd2e6228da211349574dcd44a0f67a3c76e5bd54ba8ad61070c21b852ef89e2  HandBrake-1.0.7.dmg
```

If you have a version of `HandBrake` already installed and want to verify the shasum:

1. Check the version of `HandBrake.app` installed in `/Applications`
2. Download the corresponding `.dmg` from the archive page (https://handbrake.fr/old.php)
3. Run command (shown above) [mentioned here](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/wiki/Checksums#validating-checksums) on the `.dmg` and [verify](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/wiki/Checksums#version-102) it matches
4. If the returned shasums match the corresponding version mount the `.dmg`
5. Finally, run the following commands:

*shasum -a 1*:

```
$ shasum -a 1 /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake && \
shasum -a 1 /Volumes/HandBrake-1.0.2/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
```

**Result**:

```
95017f8cc3d634d71b45407830d22e65a9098cb8  /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
95017f8cc3d634d71b45407830d22e65a9098cb8  /Volumes/HandBrake-1.0.2/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
```

*shasum -a 256*:

```
$ shasum -a 256 /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake && \
shasum -a 256 /Volumes/HandBrake-1.0.2/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
```

**Result**:

```
200c8ace634f792bffd3142f96c2187943c0243a441363220202552eb804dcec  /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
200c8ace634f792bffd3142f96c2187943c0243a441363220202552eb804dcec  /Volumes/HandBrake-1.0.2/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
```

If the hashes match (showing twice each command) then you'll know the binary is legit.

Comment: Thanks, i tried that but still got a blank response, see screenshot here : http://imgur.com/a/mRwBA

Comment: The original command seems to be way off, where did you obtain it from? I edited my answer and normally you would want to check a particular binarie's shasum. Do you know which file in the HandBrake bundle is suspected to have been infected with the malware? You might need to modify the path of your HandBrake.app in the command if it's not the same as what I've shown.

Comment: Thanks, ive just run your new commands and they seem to work fine. Re. where the original command came from this was from the hnadbrake github page [here] (https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/wiki/Checksums). Im not 100% sure which bundle is suspected of being infected  but i think its the OSX version downloaded from the the main handbrake.fr site. Thanks for all your help on this !

Comment: When i ran the updated commands i got the following : `$ shasum -a 1 /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
95017f8cc3d634d71b45407830d22e65a9098cb8  /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake` and `$ shasum -a 256 /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
200c8ace634f792bffd3142f96c2187943c0243a441363220202552eb804dcec  /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake
Sams-MacBook-Pro:~ Sam$ ` - i couldnt see either of those hashes listed as correct, does that mean i have an infected version ?

Comment: Yeah they are checking the shasum against the downloaded uninstalled `.dmg` version that would be in your `~/Downloads` folder, the original command works fine for that. In order to check already installed versions you would have to check them against the `HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake` versions from each .app bundle on the corresponding `.dmg` most likely. :/

Comment: @sam, Which version of HandBrake were you checking with the command `shasum -a 1 /Applications/HandBrake.app/Contents/MacOS/HandBrake`?

Comment: according to when i right click on the application and go to properties im running handbrake version 1.0.2. My mac is running OSX 10.10.5

Comment: The shasum from the binaries match against the ones from the legit `.dmg` on the HandBrake website, so you are not infected. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144175/discussion-between-sam-and-lll).